# wicket input ascii (control) characters in form

Tags: java, forms, character, wicket

I'm running into an issue in one of my tests, which basically checks if the input set in a `FORM` `INPUT` element gets correctly set in the component's model.

I had a randomized test put 1024 random ascii characters into the form like this:

```
final String comment = RandomStringUtils.random(1024);
    {
        final OkCancelWithCommentPanel panel = new OkCancelWithCommentPanel("component");

        this.wicketTester.startComponentInPage(panel);

        final FormTester formTester = this.wicketTester.newFormTester("component:form");
        formTester.setValue("comment", comment);
        formTester.submit("ok");
        Assertions.assertThat(panel.getCommentModel().getObject()).isEqualTo(comment);

    }
```

Some values seem to be removed, others escaped, for example `\u0017`. I could not find the expected behaviour in the docs, where should I look for what is expected by Wicket?

When running on the first 255 characters:

Expected:

```
"|b 

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþ"
```

Actual:

```
"!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþ"
```

In hex:

```
Expected :"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"
Actual   :"2122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7fc280c281c282c283c284c285c286c287c288c289c28ac28bc28cc28dc28ec28fc290c291c292c293c294c295c296c297c298c299c29ac29bc29cc29dc29ec29fc2a0c2a1c2a2c2a3c2a4c2a5c2a6c2a7c2a8c2a9c2aac2abc2acc2adc2aec2afc2b0c2b1c2b2c2b3c2b4c2b5c2b6c2b7c2b8c2b9c2bac2bbc2bcc2bdc2bec2bfc380c381c382c383c384c385c386c387c388c389c38ac38bc38cc38dc38ec38fc390c391c392c393c394c395c396c397c398c399c39ac39bc39cc39dc39ec39fc3a0c3a1c3a2c3a3c3a4c3a5c3a6c3a7c3a8c3a9c3aac3abc3acc3adc3aec3afc3b0c3b1c3b2c3b3c3b4c3b5c3b6c3b7c3b8c3b9c3bac3bbc3bcc3bdc3be"
```

Comment: What kind of issues you face ? Please give some examples

Comment: I guess it is related to url encoding. This is what the browser would do.

Comment: @martin-g I tried adding the output, but that is a bit messy as I can't paste it here as well. I'll try to output a hex difference

Comment: With unarmed eye the only difference I see is the missing "|b ". But the hex version is totally different... I'd put breakpoints in Wicket's UrlDecoder and UrlEncoder and see whether something goes off there. In any case I would expect trimming of non-printable characters.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/d266b17059122c8675d5174851ab132adeb91661/wicket-util/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/util/encoding/UrlEncoder.java#L303 in particular

Comment: During testing there's no encoding taking place. I've added your usage of RandomStringUtils to Wicket's FormTesterTest and it works as expected.

Comment: @svenmeier with 'works as expected' do you mean there should be no change between the posted data and the String in the model?

Comment: @RobAu yes, just added your lines to https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/d266b17059122c8675d5174851ab132adeb91661/wicket-core/src/test/java/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/FormTesterTest.java#L73